# Documents getting lost after insertion in sharded MongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have MongoDB cluster with 2 shards and 3 replica sets in each shard.My 3 config servers are running on one single system and my query router i.e Mongos client is running on another machine.I ran the following command 200 times for inserting 200 unique documents

```
db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2});
```

Shard key for My collection is

```
sh.shardCollection("DatabaseName.CollectionName", { "key1": 1, "key2": 1 } );
```

But when i get count of documents on same collection, that differs with count of documents i have inserted

```
mongos> db.CollectionName.find().count()
197
```

So is it like my 3 documents are not inserted?If yes then where are they getting lost and why?

Comment: Is this reproducible? Can you write a short mongo shell script that adds the documents to reproduce this and add it to the question? What version of MongoDB is this?

Comment: I have copied db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2}); from text file consisting of such 200 statements all terminated at newline and pasted directly over mongos shell. I am using 2.6.5 version of MongoDB

Comment: Can you include an actual script? If I try the same thing, it works just fine for me, so I'd like to see *exactly* what you're doing, which means code.

Comment: I had text file which contains

Comment: @wdberkeley I had text file which contains following 200 line terminated by ; and newline as follows db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2}); db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2}); db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2}); db.CollectionName.insert({"key1":value1,"key2":value2});             I simply copied these 200 lines and pasted it on Mongos console.After that i checked count.

Comment: I think you should double check how many times you are inserting - this works fine for me, and if there were a bug like this I'd think we see it 10000 times a day.

Comment: @wdberkeley I got mistake. When i inserted 20 records at a time in same fashion as above it gives me correct count.So may be when i paste 200 lines on mongos shell some lines are getting skipped and i am getting less count.